# How to determine which meteor packages are being used in my meteor project

Tags: meteor

I have a rather large meteor project and have installed several meteor packages.  I did this just to try out a meteor package to see if the package would work for my project.  Unfortunately, I did not uninstall those packages after determining that I did not need those packages installed in my project.  To uninstall I use the following command:

```sh
meteor remove <package-name>
```

Now I have a number of packages in my meteor project that I probably am not using.  I can see a list of the packages that I am using by executing the following command:

```sh
meteor list
```

How can I determine if the packages that I have installed in my meteor project are actually being used in the project that I am working on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a great question! There is no best-practice I'm aware of -- and certainly no tool in meteor itself that helps with this, so scripting is the way to go.

For that, if you are strict about always importing things you use, rather than relying on globals exported by the packages, then this will work:

```sh
for n in $(cat .meteor/packages | grep ^[^#] | cut -d '@' -f 1 | xargs); do
  echo;
  echo $n;
  grep ^import.*meteor/$n -R server/ client/ imports/; # list all sub-folders here, but omit node_modules
done
```

This will give you a list like this:

```
packageName1:
somefile.js:import something from 'meteor/packageName1';
..

packageName2:

packageName3:
somefileElse.js:import something from 'meteor/packageName3';
```

Hence, you will be able to see which packages are not imported anywhere.

Again, this is just an approximation (a sufficient condition for a package being used, but not a necessary one). So packages that show empty may still be used, but only via globals they export, rather than the new export/import semantics.